# Postback clear my Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I need to save all records in my ASP `GridView`, I'm using jQuery to add/delete rows but when I click on the "save" button,  it fires a postback and my `GridView` empties before executing my `INSERT` Statement (Stored Procedure). How can i avoid my `GridView` resetting?

This is my code to add new rows via jQuery:

```
var newRow = $("<tr>");
var cols = "";

cols += '<td><input type="text" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price' + counter + '"/></td>';
cols += '<td><input type="text" name="DD' + counter + '"/></td>';

cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
newRow.append(cols);
// if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
$("table.order-list").append(newRow);
```

This is my table:

[image]

Comment: Seems like you are dynamically creating the html and injecting it into a physical DOM element table. Thats why you would loose the contents of the table on postback since the elements would be wiped off. This is generally not the right approach to create elements dynamically but the fastest way to fix this issue in your case would be to declare a global variable in your js and assign your dynamic generated html to that and then check if its value is empty or not. If not, then take the value of that global variable and append it to your table. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/sL391995/

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net - WebForm

this is my way, Sorry I English is So so so bad, I hope you can understand > //// <

==KeyIn==

Name.TextBox,     Price.TextBox,  street.TextBox

```
    1                 2                3 　　　　[AddRow]
 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　↓
 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　↓
 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　↓
```

== Click [AddRow] to ListView or GridView ==

ListView or GridView 「Double Check(ChecktBox) & Save & Delete」

---

```
                     Name   Price  Street
```

[ChecktBox]  [Delete]　　1　　　2　　　3

[ChecktBox]  [Delete]　　　　　　.

[ChecktBox]  [Delete]　　　　　　.

[ChecktBox]  [Delete]　　　　　　.

```
                                            　　[Save]
```

---

If you want to save your data, you must check the [Check Box]
    = Just Double Check ^^